# Selenium Troubles?

Tags: java, selenium

I've just started working with selenium, and I followed the steps [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-webdriver) to get started, however, when I run the example given on the page:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I get a bunch of compilation errors. Does anyone know what might be going on? I'm not very familiar with the system as I have just begun to use it. I followed all the instructions given on the page linked above, and the compilation errors won't go away:

```
Selenium2Example.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                          ^
  symbol:   class By
  location: package org.openqa.selenium
Selenium2Example.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                          ^
  symbol:   class WebDriver
  location: package org.openqa.selenium
Selenium2Example.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
                          ^
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: package org.openqa.selenium
Selenium2Example.java:6: error: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
                                  ^
Selenium2Example.java:7: error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
                                     ^
Selenium2Example.java:8: error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
                                     ^
Selenium2Example.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        ^
  symbol:   class WebDriver
  location: class Selenium2Example
Selenium2Example.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                               ^
  symbol:   class FirefoxDriver
  location: class Selenium2Example
Selenium2Example.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        ^
  symbol:   class WebElement
  location: class Selenium2Example
Selenium2Example.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
                                                ^
  symbol:   variable By
  location: class Selenium2Example
Selenium2Example.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class ExpectedCondition
  location: class Selenium2Example
Selenium2Example.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
             ^
  symbol:   class WebDriverWait
  location: class Selenium2Example
12 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Selenium to your classpath, so either you are not compiling using Maven, or there's a configuration error in your pom file.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the selenium jar file in your project. You can download the jar from here http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven then add [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp) dependency to your POM. If you are using ant then [download selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and add it to your classpath. just check in your project dependencies if you are able to see selenium jar files. Side Note what happens when you enter WebDriver and hit Ctrl + Space in your IDE? are you able to see intellisense pop up? if not then you have still not added selenium jar files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the reason, but check that you have hamcrest also in your classpath, along with the selenium libraries.